# Angular - Managing http requests errors

Tags: angular, http

In my Angular frontend application I need to interact with a REST webservice for the login, that returns:

- Response code 201 and a ticket number in a JSON, if the login is correct.
- Response code 403 "Forbidden", if the login is wrong.

After have been read [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http-handle-request-errors), to interact with the WS I created an Angular service with following functions:

```
 getTicket(username: string, password: string){
        const headers = new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        });
    
        const body = {
          'userId': username,
          'password': password
        };
    
        return this.http.post<any>('/alfrescoapi/-default-/public/authentication/versions/1/tickets', body, {headers: headers}).pipe(
          catchError(this.handleLoginError)
        );
      }
    
    
      private handleLoginError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
        let messageError = ''
    
        if (error.status === 0) {
          // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
          messageError = "-1"
        } else {
          // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
          // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong.
          messageError = error.status.toString()
        }
        // Return an observable with a user-facing error message.
        return throwError(() => {return messageError});
      }
```

And into the component I invoked the funtion and managed the response as following:

```
 constructor(private http: HttpClient, private sLogin: SLoginService, private router: Router){
  }

doLogin(loginForm: NgForm){

    this.sLogin.getTicket(loginForm.value.loginUsername, loginForm.value.loginPassword).subscribe({
      next: x => { 
        localStorage.setItem("datiUtente", JSON.stringify(x.entry))

        this.router.navigate(["dashp"])
      },
      error: err => {
        if(err === '403')
            console.log("Login incorrect")

        this.isLoginError = true
      }
    })
  }
```

If the login is correct, it's routing to a page, otherwise it sets a variable (isLoginError) to show a message to the user.

It's the right way to manage an http request? Both the right answer and the error. Or there is a better way?
May you write to me a clear example?

I asked this question because I not sure to have correctly understanded what Angular docs explains.

Thanks.

Comment: The best way to handle http errors is to use an interceptor https://angular.io/guide/http-interceptor-use-cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, the best way to handle http errors is to use an interceptor [Angular Interceptor Doc](https://angular.io/guide/http-interceptor-use-cases)

Here's the code i wrote for an old application:

I show the error to the user with a toast.

I check the status code to show different messages.

I put the token in the header's request.

In most recent projects i also call the `authService.logout()` method if the error status is 401

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {
    HttpErrorResponse,
    HttpEvent,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpInterceptor,
    HttpRequest,
    HttpResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable, throwError} from 'rxjs';
import {catchError, delay, map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {AuthService} from "../services/auth.service";
import {environment} from "../../../environments/environment";
import {ToastrService} from "ngx-toastr";

@Injectable()
export class HttpConfigInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(
        private authService: AuthService,
        private toastrService: ToastrService,
    ) {
    }

    getErrorMessage(error: HttpErrorResponse): string {
        if (error.error && error.error.error) {
            return error.error.error;
        }
        if (error.status === 401) {
            return 'You need to login to access this resource.';
        }
        if (error.status === 412) {
            return 'Some required fields are missing.';
        }
        if (error.status >= 500) {
            return 'Internal server error.';
        }
        return 'Ops!';
    }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const token = this.authService.getToken();

        if (token) {
            request = request.clone({headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)});
        }

        if (request.body instanceof FormData) {
            request = request.clone({headers: request.headers.delete('Content-Type')});
        } else if (!request.headers.has('Content-Type')) {
            request = request.clone({headers: request.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')});
        }

        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            delay(!environment.production ? 1000 : 0),
            map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                if (event instanceof HttpResponse && !environment.production) {
                    console.info('HttpEvent --->>> ', event);
                }
                return event;
            }),
            catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                if (!environment.production) {
                    console.error('HttpEventError --->>> ', error);
                }

                const status = error.status;

                if (!status || status > 399) {
                    console.log(error);
                    if (status >= 500) {
                        this.toastrService.error('Si è verificato un errore inaspettato. Riprova oppure contatta il webmaster!', 'Ops!');
                    } else {
                        this.toastrService.error(this.getErrorMessage(error), 'Si è verificato un errore');
                    }
                }

                return throwError(error);
            }));
    }
}
```